# Parsing key values in string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a string that I am getting from a command line application. It has the following structure:

```
-- section1 --
item11|value11
item12|value12
item13

-- section2 --
item21|value21
item22
```

what I would like is to parse this to a dict so that I can easily access the values with:

```
d['section1']['item11']
```

I already solved it for the case when there are no sections and every key has a value but I get errors otherwise. I have tried a couple things but it is getting complicated because and nothing seems to work. This is what I have now:

```
s="""
item11|value11
item12|value12
item21|value21
"""
d = {}
for l in s.split('\n'):
    print(l, l.split('|'))
    if l != '':
        d[l.split('|')[0]] = l.split('|')[1]
```

Can somebody help me extend this for the section case and when no values are present?

Comment: What is the question exactly?

Comment: This woke fine in this case . what you expect to it do ?

Comment: ...parsing the text file into nested dicts for secctions?

Comment: Can I assume **section** headers will always appear? If not, what you want to do in that case, just set them (keys, values) as root elements?

Comment: yes, there are always section headers. thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems like a perfect fit for the [ConfigParser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html) module in the standard library:

```
d = ConfigParser(delimiters='|', allow_no_value=True)
d.SECTCRE = re.compile(r"-- *(?P<header>[^]]+?) *--")  # sections regex
d.read_string(s)
```

Now you have an object that you can access like a dictionary:

```
>>> d['section1']['item11']
'value11'
>>> d['section2']['item22']   # no value case
None
```

Comment: Damn, this is freaking awesome! Kilometers above my regex+iteration manual approach.

Answer (score 1):

[Regexes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) are a good take at this:

```
import re


def parse(data):
    lines = data.split("\n") #split input into lines
    result = {}
    current_header = ""

    for line in lines:
        if line: #if the line isn't empty
            #tries to match anything between double dashes:
            match = re.match(r"^-- (.*) --$", line)
            if match: #true when the above pattern matches
                #grabs the part inside parentheses:
                current_header = match.group(1)
            else:
                #key = 1st element, value = 2nd element:
                key, value = line.split("|")
                #tries to get the section, defaults to empty section:
                section = result.get(current_header, {})
                section[key] = value #adds data to section
                result[current_header] = section #updates section into result
    return result #done.

print parse("""
-- section1 --
item1|value1
item2|value2
-- section2 --
item1|valueA
item2|valueB""")
```